# How do I get the divided values of two columns that are a result from a groupby method

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I currently have a dataframe that was made by the following example code

`df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'Count'])[['Sum']].agg('sum')`

which looks like this

| col1 | col2 | Count | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DOG | HUSKY | 600 | 1500 |
| CAT | CALICO | 200 | 3000 |
| BIRD | BLUE JAY | 1500 | 4500 |

I would like to create a new column which outputs the division of df['Sum'] and df['Count']
The expected data frame would look like this

| col1 | col2 | Count | Sum | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DOG | HUSKY | 600 | 1500 | 2.5 |
| CAT | CALICO | 200 | 3000 | 15 |
| BIRD | BLUE JAY | 1500 | 4500 | 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in the same way in pandas as you would do normal division:

```
df["Average"] = df["Sum"] / df["Count"]
```